# Tried solving this using 2nd fundamental thm of calculus... But

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Momvj.jpg)

> $(2)$ Let $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be differentiable. Let $F(x)=\int_0^{g(x)}t^2 dt$. Prove that $F'(x)=g^2(x)g'(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. If $G(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}t^2 dt$, then what is $G'(x)$?

Tried solving this problem directly calculating the derivative. But to complete that proof I found g' to be continuous... Is that really needed? If not kindly give some suggestions to solve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can easily integrate $t^2$, no? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: let $F'(g(x)) = f(g(x))$ and use the Chain Rule to calculate the derivative of $F(g(x))$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @Ennar this is rigourous analysis book... Are we allowed to solve this using High school calculus?

Comment: @Mathmafia if you want something more "rigorous", then do change of variable in the definition and then applied the first fundamental theorem. The easy way is using the second, just like I answered to you.

Comment: I don't know what you think is rigorous or not, but $\int t^2\,dt = t^3/3 + c$ is quite rigorous and so is second fundamental theorem of calculus that you mention in your title.

Comment: @Ennar Maybe he want to prove the power rule?

Comment: @DanielMuñoz, well I don't know what they want exactly, I asked, but didn't get an answer.

Comment: @DanielMuñoz yes your answer is well rigour... Thank you

Comment: @Mathmafia then give me my precious internet points :D

Comment: Why not the first? Indeed, replace $t^2$ with an arbitrary continuous function, preferably one whose antiderivative one cannot find explicitly.

Comment: @DanielMuñoz for solving it using change of variables we need g' to be continuous

Comment: @Accelerator we need to prove F'(x)=$g²(x)g'(x)$... So why do we need to calculate the derivative of F(g(x))

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx} F(g(x)) = f(g(x))g'(x)$ and then you can use the FTC Part 1 from there. You can let $f(t) = t^2$ also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First evaluate the definition of $F(x)$:

$$\int_0^{g(x)}t^2\ dt={(g(x))^3\over 3}$$

Now the prove of $F'(x)$ is just applying change rule.

Do the same for the definition of $G(x)$, then apply change rule.

EDIT:

Using the first theorem$\dots$

Let $p:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be differentiable.

Define $p(y)=t\Rightarrow p'(y)dy=dt$. Doing change of variables in $F(x)$

$$=\int_{p^{-1}(a)}^{x} (p(y))^2\ p'(y)\ dy$$

Then applying the first fundamental theorem we get:

$${d\over dx}F(x)={d\over dx}\left(\int_{p^{-1}(a)}^{x} (p(y))^2\ p'(y)\ dy\right)=(p(x))^2\ p'(x)=$$

Now let $G,q:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that:

$$G(x)=\int_{q(x)}^{p(x)}t^2\ dt$$

Then separate the integral as:

$$\int_{q(x)}^{p(x)}t^2\ dt=\int_a^{p(x)}t^2\ dt\ -\int_a^{q(x)}t^2\ dt$$

Then define $p(y)=t,\quad q(z)=t\quad\Rightarrow\quad p'(y)dy=dt,\quad q'(z)dz=dt$. Doing change of variables in $G(x)$:

$$\int_a^{p(x)}t^2\ dt\ -\int_a^{q(x)}t^2\ dt=\int_{p^{-1}(a)}^{x}(p(y))^2\ p'(y)\ dy\ -\int_{q^{-1}(a)}^{x}(q(z))^2\ q'(z)\ dz$$

then ${d\over dx}G(x):$

$${d\over dx}G(x) ={d\over dx}\left(\int_{p^{-1}(a)}^{x}(p(y))^2\ p'(y)\ dy\ -\int_{q^{-1}(a)}^{x}(q(z))^2\ q'(z)\ dz \right)$$

$$=(p(x))^2\ p'(x)-(q(x))^2\ q'(x) $$

As pointed by @Mathmafia, you need that $p,q$ be differentiable continuos, and by @TedShifrin, this work for any antidifferentiable function inside the integral.